# UIView flip animation is not animating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I'm trying to flip between a front view and a back view, like a page of a book. I ran the following test code in a view controller and no animation happened. I only saw the back view (red square) appear statically for 2 seconds. What's wrong?

```
  UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
  containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  [self.view addSubview:containerView];

  UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
  backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [containerView addSubview:backView];

  UIView *frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
  frontView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [containerView addSubview:frontView];

  [UIView transitionFromView:frontView
                      toView:backView
                    duration:2.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                      | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [containerView removeFromSuperview];
                  }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your `frontView`, `backView` and `containerView`as ivars:

```
@interface yourViewController ()
{
    UIView *backView;
    UIView *frontView;
    UIView *containerView;
}
```

Then place your view initialization code within `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[containerView addSubview:backView];

UIView *frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
frontView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[containerView addSubview:frontView];
```

And finally place your animation code within a method:

```
- (void)flippingViewTransitionAnimation
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:frontView
                        toView:backView
                      duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [containerView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

And subsequently call the above method from within `viewDidAppear`, you should then be able to see the animation run.

Comment: I found the reason for the problem. You can only animate views after they have been drawn. Thus, you cannot create the views and animate them all on the same run loop. You're solution is one way to delay the animation to a later run loop. It's also possible to delay the animation with performSelector.